# Ruby diff two strings and make an array of the parts that are the same

Tags: ruby

With Ruby, how can I get the diff between two strings, then use the identical parts as a base to split the rest?

For **example**, I have two strings (Not all strings will have this formatting):

```
String1 = "Computer: Person1, Title: King, Phone: 555-1212"
String2 = "Computer: PersonB, Title: Queen, Phone: 123-4567"
```

I would like to be able to compare (diff) the two strings so that I get the result:

```
["Computer: ",", Title:",", Phone:"]
```

then use this to reparse the original strings to get:

```
["Person1","King","555-1212"] and ["PersonB","Queen","123-4567"]
```

which I could label in db/storage with the former array.

Are there features to do this and how would I achieve these results?

The object of this is not need prior knowledge of formatting. This way just the data are analyzed for patterning and then divided as such. It may be comma delimited, new lines, spaced out, etc.

I am looking at gem "diffy" and "diff-lcs" to see if they might help split this up.

Comment: Maybe start with something like `String1.split - String2.split`?

Comment: Just tried that, and there is something to it, but it seems to also split up things that are not meant to be split up.  Such as when a date contains a time "2012-10-15, 8:00pm" which I don't believe will work

Comment: This seems a little bit underspecified at the moment. If there are no rules to the format, how do we know what constitutes a part in order to determine whether two parts are identical? for example, both of those strings contain "Person" — is "Person" an identical part? How should the algorithm determine that?

Comment: I questioned this as well.  I guess just more parts to help better determine the pattern.  Or perhaps requiring items to be broken by space/punctuation. So that if any part of a "word" is different then the whole word is different.

Comment: Question not clear. Why isn't the common parts `["Computer: Person", ", Title: ", ", Phone: ", "-"]`, for example? Your expected array is highly arbitrary, and you haven't given the rules that extract what you have.

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need is a hash, with hash you can do anything fancy.

```
>> String1 = "Computer: Person1, Title: King, Phone: 555-1212"
>> a = String1.gsub(/[^\s\:]/) { |w| "\"#{w}\"" }
>> a.insert(0, "{")
>> a.insert(-1, "}")
>> a1 = JSON.parse(a)
>> #=> {
    "Computer" => "Person1",
    "Title" => "King",
    "Phone" => "555-1212"
   }
```

Then you can request what you want in question, like

```
>> a1["Computer"]
>> #=> "Person1"
```

**Add**

And you can abstract it to a method further

```
def str_to_hash(str)
  ouput = str.gsub(/[^\s\:]/) { |w| "\"#{w}\"" }
  output.insert(0, "{").insert(-1, "}")
  JSON.parse(out)
end

>> h2 = str_to_hash(String2)
>> h2["Computer"]
>> #=>"PersonB"
```

Comment: If I understand that correctly, I won't know where to make hashes from, the data may be delivered in any manner.  Might have certain tokens or maybe none at all.

Comment: @ChrisValentine, can you ensure the data format to be consistent? or at least some consistent styles? If not, it's impossible to do anything.

Comment: Cannot ensure it, but its not impossible.  I just described how to do it in theory, I just am too new to ruby to know what functions achieve it next to character by character comparisons.

Comment: @ChrisValentine, I guess what you said is about data itself, that's sure thing, but the format is consistent. String1 and String2 are in same format. See my updated answer.

Comment: What if it is "Computer=Person1 Title=King"  or "Computer Name is Person1\nTitle is King"

Comment: hmm... if these are all, it's still possible though harder, using conditions. If there are more and you can't ensure, it's impossible. You can't parse unknown format. That's not specific to Ruby. All languages can't.

Comment: Thanks but its not impossible, Its definitely achievable with some diff components or similar.  Just need to narrow it down.

Answer (score 1):

```
String1 = "Computer: Person1, Title: King, Phone: 555-1212"
String2 = "Computer: PersonB, Title: Queen, Phone: 123-4567"

keys = String1.split - (String1.split - String2.split)

values = String1.split - keys
```

You need to find a suitable way to split for your specific data. For instance, if values are allowed to contain spaces inside double quotes, you can to something like `.split(/"?[^ ]*\ ?[^ ]*"?/)`, but there is no general solution for this, that will handle any type of data.

And then you need to clean up the resulting values.

Comment: Doesn't work, it splits the values as well since some values may have commas and spaces.  Unless I misunderstood that is.

Comment: String1.split - (String1.split - String2.split) gives me all the key fields but they are incorrectly broken up if they contain spaces :(

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry, but there is no guarantee there will be ,'s or :'s in the given strings.  They could be anything.

Comment: OKay, so what you really want is to identify "keys" in the string, which you can then use to split up the string?

Comment: Yes correct, each key being a chunk separating two areas that are different.

Answer (score 0):

Given those strings, I would rather split columns by `,`, then use the part before `:` as name of column.

There is an [longest common subsequence problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem), which has something to do, but is not smart enough to handle semantics of data.

Comment: Only my examples have comma's, in reality I just meant comparing the two for where they are the same and different.

Comment: Could you do something with "<=>" comparing character by character? If not, then perhaps give 2 or 3 different string examples so we can see what patterns there are.

Comment: @ChrisValentine What do you mean, you don't have commas in your data? How does the original data look like?

Comment: The original data can be anything.  Might be split by EOL or another delimiter or spacing.  Thats why I just wanted to compare in this manner.

Comment: @ChrisValentine In that case, the consecutive characters given by `LCS` may be a point to start with.

Answer (score 0):

```
s1 = String1.split(' ')
s2 = String2.split(' ')

s1 - s2
=> ["Person1,", "King,", "555-1212"]

s2 - s1
=> ["PersonB,", "Queen,", "123-4567"]
```

Comment: Would only work it it was guaranted to be space delimited.  Spaces might exist in keys, or it may have no spaces at all ("Key=value,Key=value")